# Passing class type into a method parameter

Tags: c#

Is there a way to pass a complex type as a parameter into a method. 
I would like to implement a more generic method listed below.

I would like to pass View (class) name into the method, instead of explicitly specifying `'ParticipantSummaryView'` in teh case below. Thanks

```
    private void InitializePdfView(ParticipantBasic selectedParticipant,
                                          string regionName, string viewName)
    {
        IRegion region = this.regionManager.Regions[regionName];
        if (region == null) return;

        // Check to see if we need to create an instance of the view.
        var view = region.GetView(viewName) as ParticipantSummaryView;
        if (view == null)
        {
            // Create a new instance of the EmployeeDetailsView using the Unity container.
            view = this.container.Resolve<ParticipantSummaryView>();

            // Add the view to the main region. This automatically activates the view too.
            region.Add(view, viewName);
        }
        else
        {
            // The view has already been added to the region so just activate it.
            region.Activate(view);
        }

        // Set the current employee property on the view model.
        var viewModel = view.DataContext as ParticipantSummaryViewModel;
        if (viewModel != null)
        {
            viewModel.CurrentParticipant = selectedParticipant;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You are already passing a class — well, an instance of a class — into a method. `selectedParticipant` is an instance of `ParticipantBasic` which is a class (a "complex type"). What's your problem?

Comment: You told it : "a more *generic* method". That's exactly the point :)
Please have a look on how .NET Generics works : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
 private void InitializePdfView<TView, TViewModel>(ParticipantBasic selectedParticipant, string regionName, string viewName)
{
    IRegion region = this.regionManager.Regions[regionName];
    if (region == null) return;

    // Check to see if we need to create an instance of the view.
    var view = region.GetView(viewName) as TView;
    if (view == null)
    {
        // Create a new instance of the EmployeeDetailsView using the Unity container.
        view = this.container.Resolve<TView>();

        // Add the view to the main region. This automatically activates the view too.
        region.Add(view, viewName);
    }
    else
    {
        // The view has already been added to the region so just activate it.
        region.Activate(view);
    }

    // Set the current employee property on the view model.
    var viewModel = view.DataContext as TViewModel;
    if (viewModel != null)
    {
        viewModel.CurrentParticipant = selectedParticipant;
    }
}
```

However, you will need to implement a constraint for your `TViewModel` because calling `.CurrentParticipant` on *any* type is not possible. You will need to make the `viewModel` variable `dynamic` or use a proper interface or base class for the viewmodel that has such a method.

Calling this could look like:

```
InitializePdfView<ParticipantSummaryView, ParticipantSummaryViewModel>(selectedParticipant, regionName, viewName);
```